# How to dynamically arrange elements in twig

Tags: twig

Lets think of the situation where you have to print out a set of filters (categories, options, price range, manufacturers etc ...).

The frontend designer may want to arrange these elements in many way (for example price range and manufacturers on the same row while the others are stacked on each other).

**My first attempt:**

Put each rendered filter in a block, then let the frontend designer to decide how/where to render the blocks in the template

*The problem:* since the filter set is dynamic, I must be able to set block name dynamically say via a variable but it seems not possible at the moment.

**My second attempt:**

Thinking along the same line, it may be possible to assign the rendered filter in an associative array then let the frontend designer decides where to print out

*The problem:* in the php template twig does seem have the render which returns the output that can be assigned, doesn't seem to be the case when using pure twig language.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll first create a `categoryFilter.html.twig`, `optionsFilter.html.twig`, `priceRangeFilter.html.twig`... each containing a specific filter without a special arrangement.

And I'll write a global `filters.html.twig` that contains the layout, and [`{{ include }}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html) all filters at the right place.

In such way, your designer just have to update `filters.html.twig` to change the layout.